# How to show which account generated the highest amount of interest and display that account from structs in c++?

Tags: c++

The challenge I've been assigned is to:

[image]

My program so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS =8;
struct Accounts
{
    int AccountNumber;
    double Balance;
    int DaysSinceDebited;

};

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct Accounts AccountsArr[MAXACCOUNTS] = {{1001,4254.40,20},
        {7940,27006.25,35},
        {4382,123.50,2},
        {2651,85326.92,14},
        {3020,657.0,5},
        {7168,7423.34,360},
        {6245,4.99,1},
        {9342,107864.44,45}
    };

    for (i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        if ((AccountsArr[i].Balance > 10000) || (AccountsArr[i].DaysSinceDebited > 30))
        {
            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.06;
        }
        else
        {
            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.03;
        }
    cout << AccountsArr[i].Balance << " ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

How would I now output which account generated the highest amount of interest and display the relevant account number?

Updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS =8;
struct Accounts
{
    int AccountNumber;
    double Balance;
    int DaysSinceDebited;
    double Interest;

};

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct Accounts AccountsArr[MAXACCOUNTS] = {{1001,4254.40,20,0},
        {7940,27006.25,35,0},
        {4382,123.50,2,0},
        {2651,85326.92,14,0},
        {3020,657.0,5,0},
        {7168,7423.34,360,0},
        {6245,4.99,1,0},
        {9342,107864.44,45,0}
    };
    double HighestInterest = 0;
    cout << "Acct No, " << "Balance "  << "Interest" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        if ((AccountsArr[i].Balance > 10000) || (AccountsArr[i].DaysSinceDebited > 30))
        {
//            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.06;
              AccountsArr[i].Interest = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 0.06;
        }
        else
        {
//            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.03;
              AccountsArr[i].Interest = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 0.03;
        }

        if (HighestInterest < AccountsArr[i].Interest)
        {
            HighestInterest = AccountsArr[i].Interest;
        }
           cout << AccountsArr[i].AccountNumber << "     ";
           cout << AccountsArr[i].Balance << "     ";
           cout << AccountsArr[i].Interest << endl;
    }

    cout << "The highest interest is: " << HighestInterest << " Account Number: " << AccountsArr[i].AccountNumber;

    return 0;
}
```

This now outputs the highest interest but not the associated account, I know it's because the AccountsArr[i].AccountNumber is outside the for loop but if it's inside it works but prints every single time, how can I stop this?

Updated Code v2:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS =8;
struct Accounts
{
    int AccountNumber;
    double Balance;
    int DaysSinceDebited;
    double Interest;

};

int main()
{
    int j;
    int i;
    struct Accounts AccountsArr[MAXACCOUNTS] = {{1001,4254.40,20,0},
        {7940,27006.25,35,0},
        {4382,123.50,2,0},
        {2651,85326.92,14,0},
        {3020,657.0,5,0},
        {7168,7423.34,360,0},
        {6245,4.99,1,0},
        {9342,107864.44,45,0}
    };
    double HighestInterest = 0;
    cout << "Acct No, " << "Balance "  << "Interest" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        if ((AccountsArr[i].Balance > 10000) || (AccountsArr[i].DaysSinceDebited > 30))
        {
//            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.06;
              AccountsArr[i].Interest = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 0.06;
        }
        else
        {
//            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.03;
              AccountsArr[i].Interest = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 0.03;
        }

        if (HighestInterest < AccountsArr[i].Interest)
        {
            HighestInterest = AccountsArr[i].Interest;
        }
           cout << AccountsArr[i].AccountNumber << "     ";
           cout << AccountsArr[i].Balance << "     ";
           cout << AccountsArr[i].Interest << endl;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < MAXACCOUNTS; j++)
    {
        while (j = 7) {
        cout << "The highest interest is: " << HighestInterest << " Account Number: " << AccountsArr[j].AccountNumber;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've now include a while loop and for loop to overcome my previous problem, but this seems to be over complicating something which should seem easy to fix?

Final Version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS =8;
struct Accounts
{
    int AccountNumber;
    double Balance;
    int DaysSinceDebited;
    double Interest;

};

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct Accounts AccountsArr[MAXACCOUNTS] = {{1001,4254.40,20,0},
        {7940,27006.25,35,0},
        {4382,123.50,2,0},
        {2651,85326.92,14,0},
        {3020,657.0,5,0},
        {7168,7423.34,360,0},
        {6245,4.99,1,0},
        {9342,107864.44,45,0}
    };
    double HighestInterest = 0;
    int HighestAccountNumber = 0;
    cout << "Acct No, " << "Balance "  << "Interest" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        if ((AccountsArr[i].Balance > 10000) || (AccountsArr[i].DaysSinceDebited > 30))
        {
//            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.06;
              AccountsArr[i].Interest = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 0.06;
        }
        else
        {
//            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.03;
              AccountsArr[i].Interest = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 0.03;
        }

        if (HighestInterest < AccountsArr[i].Interest)
        {
            HighestInterest = AccountsArr[i].Interest;
            HighestAccountNumber = AccountsArr[i].AccountNumber;
        }
           cout << AccountsArr[i].AccountNumber << "     ";
           cout << AccountsArr[i].Balance << "     ";
           cout << AccountsArr[i].Interest << endl;
    }

    cout << "The highest interest is: " << HighestInterest << " Account Number: " << HighestAccountNumber;

    return 0;
}
```

After some advice about storing the account number, I was able to solve my problem!

Comment: In your sample code, I don't see anything attempting to work out which account had the highest interest rate. What approaches to solving the problem have you tried so far?

Comment: I've now updated the code with the attempt I made at fixing it, like I stated it stores the highest interest value but fails to locate the associated account unless it's inside the for loop. However, if it's in the for loop it prints each time

Comment: You could consider keeping track of a reference to the highest account, rather than storing just the highest interest. `Account& highestAccount = AccountsArr[0]; for { ... if(heightestAccount.Interest < AccountsArr[i].Interest) { heighestAccount = AccountsArr[i]; } } cout << highestAccount.AccountNumber;`

Comment: I've no overcome the issue I had which basically fixes my problem, but it seems to be over complicating the issue completely

Comment: That for/while combination doesn't do what you think it does. It *always* prints Account number 7, which I assume happens to be the correct account in this case. If you change the order of accounts you'll see you get the wrong one.

Comment: What you need is a way to remember which of the accounts was the highest (i.e. which value of i corresponds to the highest account)

Comment: After reading your comments I realised you're right about the while loop and was able to store the account number to a variable, which fixed my problem!

Comment: @Henry I'm not a C++ expert, but couldn't some of those parenthesis have been omitted?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS =8;
struct Accounts
{
    int AccountNumber;
    double Balance;
    int DaysSinceDebited;
    double Interest;

};

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct Accounts AccountsArr[MAXACCOUNTS] = {{1001,4254.40,20,0},
        {7940,27006.25,35,0},
        {4382,123.50,2,0},
        {2651,85326.92,14,0},
        {3020,657.0,5,0},
        {7168,7423.34,360,0},
        {6245,4.99,1,0},
        {9342,107864.44,45,0}
    };
    double HighestInterest = 0;
    int HighestAccountNumber = 0;
    cout << "Acct No, " << "Balance "  << "Interest" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        if ((AccountsArr[i].Balance > 10000) || (AccountsArr[i].DaysSinceDebited > 30))
        {
//            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.06;
              AccountsArr[i].Interest = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 0.06;
        }
        else
        {
//            AccountsArr[i].Balance = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 1.03;
              AccountsArr[i].Interest = AccountsArr[i].Balance * 0.03;
        }

        if (HighestInterest < AccountsArr[i].Interest)
        {
            HighestInterest = AccountsArr[i].Interest;
            HighestAccountNumber = AccountsArr[i].AccountNumber;
        }
           cout << AccountsArr[i].AccountNumber << "     ";
           cout << AccountsArr[i].Balance << "     ";
           cout << AccountsArr[i].Interest << endl;
    }

    cout << "The highest interest is: " << HighestInterest << " Account Number: " << HighestAccountNumber;

    return 0;
}
```

I was able to eventually solve my problem by storing the account number to a variable.

Comment: Well done! This code looks good. One way you could make it slightly simpler is to store one `HighestAccountIndex` with the value of `i`, and then access `AccountsArr[HeighestAccountIndex]` when you need to both the highest interest and highest account number. That way you make sure the two never get our of sync.

Answer (score 0):

You should add interests field into the structure and check it in the loop

```
struct Accounts
{
    int AccountNumber;
    double Balance;
    int DaysSinceDebited;
    int interestsValue;
};

int maxInteresrtsValue = AccountsArr[o].interestsValue;
for (i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        if (AccountsArr[o].interestsValue > maxInteresrtsValue)
        ... perform actions needed here
    }
```

Comment: I've taken your advice and now added Interest to the struct, however as stated above I'm having an issue with showing the associated account without the statement printing everytime